# Atualizar mensagem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Possuo a seguinte tela:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="listaEncomendas">
            <p:tabView id="viewFull">
                <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="false" globalOnly="true" />
                <p:tab title="PENDENTES">
                    <p:panel id="horizontal" header="Cadastrar Encomenda" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal"
                        toggleTitle="Cadastrar Encomenda" collapsed="true">
                        <h:panelGrid id="cadastro" columns="3">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Código" for="codigo" />
                            <p:inputText id="codigo" value="#{encomendaController.encomenda.codigo}" required="true" />
                            <p:message for="codigo" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Loja/Origem" for="loja" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="loja" value="#{encomendaController.encomenda.loja}" required="true">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{enumHelper.obterLojas()}" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean.nome}" itemValue="#{bean.nome}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:message for="loja" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" action="#{encomendaController.salvar}" update="cadastro,:listaEncomendas:viewFull:messages" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:spacer height="10px" />
                    <p:dataTable id="resultadoPendentes" rows="10" paginator="true">
                        <p:column styleClass="botoesGrid">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Código" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Situação" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Data/Hora Ocorrência" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Loja" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="ENTREGUES">
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="TODAS">
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

O que acontece é o seguinte:

O meu `p:messages` funciona perfeitamente quando está abaixo do `p:tab` aí no update do `p:commandButton` eu o referencio pelo id. Mas no cenário acima não funciona, ou seja, a mensagem não é exibida na tela. Alguém sabe se isso é possível? Meu update está errado ?

Comment: tente colocando o `<p:messages>` como filha direta de `<h:form>`. Como está creio que sua mensagem nunca será exibida, pois (se não me engano) `<p:tabView>` apenas pode ter `<p:tab>` como filhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Tab é um conteiner JSF
Se o p:commandButton  esta dentro do tab e o p:messages fora você deve no update informar o caminho todo.
Ex. :listaEncomendas:messages

Pelo que pude notar, salvo falta de conhecimento de minha parte, entre o tabView e tab realmente não funciona.

Experimente deixar fora do tab deixando o parametro globalOnly = "false"

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="false" globalOnly="false" />
<p:tabView id="viewFull">
        <p:tab title="PENDENTES">
         ...
         <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar"  update="cadastro,:listaEncomendas:messages" />
```

Ou dentro do Tab desejado.

```
<p:tabView id="viewFull">
        <p:tab title="PENDENTES">
             <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="false" globalOnly="false" />
              ...
             <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar"  update="cadastro,:listaEncomendas:viewFull:messages" />
```

Comment: Tentei isso inclusive meu exemplo está assim.

Comment: Inspecione como esta o html no final. Acho que o messages ou fica fora do conteiner ou dentro de um tab.  Entre o tabViwer e o tab acho que realmente não funcionar.

Comment: Complementei a resposta com base em alguns testes que fiz.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, acabou que o `growl` ficou melhor e está funcionando.